# Get API response to a function and populate controls

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have created a react application where i am fetching an API and getting the response. below are the code,

```
export class EmpDetails extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {        
    super(props);
    this.state = {};

    this.updateEmpName = this.updateEmpName.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {    
    this.handleProp(nextProps);
    if(nextProps){
      this.GetData(nextProps);
    } else {
      console.log("Emp number not set");
    }
  }

  GetData(props, EmpCollection) {
    this.ApiCall(props);      
  }

  ApiCall(props) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:8081/getdata',      
      type: 'POST',
      data: {Empnumber:props.Empnumber},
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({EmpCollection: data.EmpCollection});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.Empnumber, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  }

  getInitialState(){
    return {
      EmpCollection: []
    }
  }

  updateEmpName(e) {
    this.setState({EmpName: e.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <div >
          <input
            type="text"
            id="EmpName"
            placeholder="Emp Name" 
            value={this.state.EmpName}
            onChange={this.updateEmpName} />
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

I am able to get the response and can use it only in `render()`. and I wanted API response in `GetData()` or any other method so that i can set the state of there and populate controls. not in render. any idea how can i achieve this?

Comment: You should probably go throught the redux docs. You're data fetch functions should be in actions and not in your components

Comment: ok... but here i am storing data to array. and also i am able to get the correct response from ajax. then why i need to use redux?

Comment: You don't need to use redux, especially for something simple. Redux adds additional complexity that pays off big time when your app is bigger (handling the data fetching inside the components becomes an unmaintainable mess), but for simple things it's perfectly ok to just use plain react and mash data-fetching into your components.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to save the response somewhere. I could be just variable outside of component or it could be component property. For example,

```js
class YourComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    // your code ...
    this.response = null;
  }
  
  callApi() {
    const self = this;
    
    $.ajax({
      // your code ...
      success: function(response) {
        self.response = response;
      }
    })
  }
  
  someOtherMethod() {
    console.log(this.response)
  }

}
```

Comment: in my code i have declared a array EmpCollection. do i really need some other variable to store?

Comment: No, but you need to declare your `EmpCollection` array inside `consctructor` function. `getInitialState` is a method for es5 syntax ( React.createClass() )

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make api call in life cycle method `componentDidMount` not in `componentWillReceiveProps` as recommended in react docs.

Need to change your api call method a little bit.

```
ApiCall(props) {
    return $.ajax({
       url: 'http://localhost:8081/getdata',      
       type: 'POST',
       data: {Empnumber:props.Empnumber}
    }).fail((responseData) => {
        if (responseData.responseCode) {
            console.error(responseData.responseCode);
        }
    });
}
```

Basically above call will return you a jquery promise which you can use later.

Now in what ever method you want to make ApiCall just use like this -

```
 GetData(props,EmpCollection)
 {
    this.ApiCall(props)
        .then(
            function(data){
              console.log(data);
              // set the state here
            },
            function(error){
              console.log(error);
           }
    );      
 }
```